# Guide to use Sqlite on xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite

Does anyone know a guide to use sqlite on the latest version on xcode (11.5)?

I'm learning how to build an IOS app and need to use a database in my project. However, most of the guides I found are old and doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't really changed that much from version to version.

The Ray Wenderlich tutorial covers pretty much everything: https://www.raywenderlich.com/6620276-sqlite-with-swift-tutorial-getting-started

The only bit missing is adding the library if you don't use their sample project, but you can find that here (up to the initialising database section): https://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

If it's your first app on iOS, I'd recommend using an SQLite library, or CoreData/other DB. The SQLite API you get just talking straight to the library is pretty ugly and doesn't bridge to Swift super nicely.

Comment: For https://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/ I got lost when I couldn't create an objective C class. I only see objective C file

Comment: Update: The raywenderlich guide works, but it hides a lot of information. It lets me use their function and all, but it doesn't teach me how to implement sqlite into my own project.

Comment: I gave up on sqlite for ios, because the data can't be shared with other people unless they have physical access to your phone.